# VS Code: Disable 'format on save' for specific tag in Twig

Tags: twig, visual-studio-code, twig-extension

I have this basic template structure:

```
// base.html.twig
{% include "_parts/header.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% include "_parts/footer.html.twig" %}
```

I have the setting "Format on save" checked.

Here is the `_part/header.html.twig` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            {% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}
        </title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>{{ config('SITE_NAME') }}</h3>
```

**Unfortunatly, on save, the formatter adds closing tags: `</body>` and `</html>`**
But those must be in `_parts/footer.twig`

---

Also, the formatter is changing:

```
{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}
```

into:

```
{% block title %}
    Welcome!
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to disable it for 'block' tag too?

Thank you.
Ed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this (i was searching for something similar) but I have a little advice about that: just make sure every template is complete by himself in his structure will ease the task.

For example, a base skeleton beginning with `<html>`, ending with `</html>`, containing (via include) a header beginning with `<head>`, ending with `</head>`, same goes for body, and footer, etc.

In your example, the `<body>` tag in `_parts/header.html.twig` should be in the body, or at least in the base.

This way you will see the template is valid, so will the formatter.